# Single buffered EGL surface

Tags: display

I have an OpenGL ES 2 app that's working fine with the default window surface:

```
eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface( eglDisplay, config, nativeWindow, NULL );
```

When I try and make it single buffered, like this:

```
static const EGLint surf_attribute_list[] = {
    EGL_RENDER_BUFFER, EGL_SINGLE_BUFFER,
    EGL_NONE // attribute list is termintated with EGL_NONE
};
eglSurface = eglCreateWindowSurface( eglDisplay, config, nativeWindow, surf_attribute_list );
```

I no longer see anything drawn on the screen.

Is there something else I need to do to switch from double to single buffering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unable to solve this. I needed single-buffering so that I could leave content on existing framebuffer between one frame and the next, and ended up using an FBO to achieve this.

Comment: It is 10 years later and I have the same issue. FBO is such a waste, let's make a third buffer to solve not being able to use one buffer. But it is what it is...